# Blackberry - how programmatically unblock blocked caller Id

Tags: blackberry

how can phone number be shown if it was hidden by the call initiator?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not possible, it's hidden at the network level and not at the handset level.

Comment: Then, how services like TrapCall work?
AFAIK, the phone call forwarded to service like TrapCall and than something is done on its side... But if they can unblock forwarded phone call, then there should be the way to do it on handset side?

BTW, how, more or less, they unblock it?

Comment: If you follow trapcalls instructions you will be asked to divert your phone to their toll-free number. Toll-free numbers are a bit of a loophole when it comes to caller ID, they can see it because the toll-free owner is paying the bills. But all of this is still happening at the network level and although they provide clients it's their services proprietary api that it returning a caller ID obtained at the network level from tdm or sip headers.

Comment: Actually after checking it out they do an extra step which is to loop the call back to you with the calling party spoofed to the previously blocked one. So I don't think there is even a need for a proprietary api, it can be done completely at the network level.

Comment: @Ray Vahey: Do you know how to block perticular call from our application?